# NHibernate:Is there any way to get HQL or SQL from Criteria?

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, hql

I think that there are times that we want to get `HQL` or `SQL` from a criteria. Take the following example :
Suppose we want to delete all objects of type T with-in a list of ids :

```
public class Repostiroy<T>
{
     public void Delete(object[] ids){...}

}
```

I know that we can implement it like this :

```
Session.CreateQuery<T>(String.Format("from {0} where id in(:ids)",typeof(T).Name).SetListParameter("ids",ids).ExecuteUpdate();
```

But for a generic method it can have some problems (type name and id field name for example).
When you use a Criteria in NHibernate it will generate the `HQL` and `SQL` for you but I don't know a way to extract it from Criteria.Suppose we have a method called `ToHQL` for Criteria the we can do something like this :

```
Session.CreateQuery<T>("delete "+Session.CreateCriteria<T>().Add(Restrictions.In(Projections.Id(),ids)).ToHQL()).ExecuteUpdate();
```

The question is how I can implement `ToHQL` and `ToSQL` ?

**UPDATE**

The same methods could be applied for `Session.Query<T>` where you can use `NHibernate Linq Provider` to create the `HQL` and or `SQL` for you

Answer (score 0):

Well by looking under the hood of NHibernate I managed to write thses two extensions for Criteria :

**ToISqlCommands:**

```
public static IEnumerable<ISqlCommand> ToISqlCommands(this ICriteria criteria)
        {
            var criteriaImp = criteria as CriteriaImpl;
            if (criteriaImp == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            var implementors = criteriaImp.Session.Factory.GetImplementors(criteriaImp.EntityOrClassName);
            var loaders = new CriteriaLoader[implementors.Length];
            for (var i = 0; i < implementors.Length; i++)
            {
                loaders[i] = new CriteriaLoader((IOuterJoinLoadable) typeof(SessionImpl).GetMethod("GetOuterJoinLoadable",BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(criteriaImp.Session,new object[]{implementors[i]}), criteriaImp.Session.Factory, criteriaImp, implementors[i], criteriaImp.Session.EnabledFilters);
            }

            return
                loaders.Select(
                    loader => loader.CreateSqlCommand(loader.Translator.GetQueryParameters(), criteriaImp.Session));
        }
```

and **ToIDbCommnads:**

```
public static IEnumerable<IDbCommand> ToIDbCommands(this ICriteria criteria)
        {
             var criteriaImp = criteria as CriteriaImpl;
            if (criteriaImp == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            var implementors = criteriaImp.Session.Factory.GetImplementors(criteriaImp.EntityOrClassName);
            var loaders = new CriteriaLoader[implementors.Length];
            for (var i = 0; i < implementors.Length; i++)
            {
                loaders[i] = new CriteriaLoader((IOuterJoinLoadable) typeof(SessionImpl).GetMethod("GetOuterJoinLoadable",BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(criteriaImp.Session,new object[]{implementors[i]}), criteriaImp.Session.Factory, criteriaImp, implementors[i], criteriaImp.Session.EnabledFilters);
            }

            return
                loaders.Select(
                    loader => (IDbCommand)loader.GetType().GetMethod("PrepareQueryCommand", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(loader,new object[]{ loader.Translator.GetQueryParameters(),false, criteriaImp.Session}));
        }
```

These extensiosn are not what I really had in mind but they can do the job.
`ISqlCommand` is a `NHibernate` interface that has sql query and its query parameters definitions in it.

**UPDATE**

still working on `NHibernate Linq Provider`